# Can I run the OS X installer even after I delete main disk

Tags: recovery, internet-recovery

I'm trying to reinstall OS X on my girlfriend's Mac and when I go to recovery menu and select to install OS X from the menu, the system proceeds to start download *components*, which fails.

I've thought about using disk utility to delete the main drive and then mount a new one and try the OS X installation from the recovery menu again in hopes it just fails because there isn't enough space for the *components*. But I am afraid to try it because I worry the recovery image will be deleted as well and I won't be able to run the OS X reinstallation after I have deleted and recreated the main disk.

**Is this a real risk or should I go ahead at try it?** *Components* seems to be a lot to download so I'm thinking it probably is the OS image so me clearing the drive completely shouldn't be an issue, but I have no experience with anything Apple so prefer to have people to blame after my girlfriend asks why did I brick her Mac.

Comment: If you can boot normally into OS X then create an OS X USB Installer. See,  [Create a bootable installer for OS X](https://support.apple.com/HT201372) or if not see, [How to reinstall OS X](https://support.apple.com/HT204904).

Comment: Can you answerize your comment? I've went the bootable installer route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can boot normally into OS X then create an OS X USB Installer. See, [Create a bootable installer for OS X](https://support.apple.com/HT201372) (quoted below) or if not see, [How to reinstall OS X](https://support.apple.com/HT204904).

---

> Use the 'createinstallmedia' command in Terminal
>
> 1. Download the OS X installer from the Mac App Store. Quit the installer if it opens automatically after downloading. The installer
>      will be in your Applications folder.
> 2. Mount your USB flash drive or other volume. You could also use a secondary internal partition.
> 3. Open the Terminal app, which is in the Utilities folder of your Applications folder.
> 4. Use the `createinstallmedia` command in Terminal to create the bootable installer. Examples of this command are in the next section.
>      For detailed usage instructions, make sure that the appropriate
>      Install OS X app is in your Applications folder, then enter one of the
>      following paths in Terminal:
>
> Path for El Capitan:
>
> ```
> /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia
> ```
>
> Path for Yosemite:
>
> ```
> /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia
> ```
>
> Path for Mavericks:
>
> ```
> /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia
> ```
>
> Examples
>
> This is the basic syntax of the command. Replace `volumepath` with the
>   path to your USB flash drive or other volume, and replace
>   `installerpath` with the path to the Install OS X app.
>
> ```
> createinstallmedia --volume volumepath --applicationpath installerpath
> ```
>
> The following examples assume that the OS X installer is in your
>   Applications folder and the name of your USB flash drive or other
>   volume is MyVolume:
>
> Example for El Capitan:
>
> ```
> sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume
> ```
>
> /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\
>   Capitan.app
>
> Example for Yosemite:
>
> ```
> sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume
> ```
>
> /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\
>   Yosemite.app
>
> Example for Mavericks:
>
> ```
> sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume
> ```
>
> /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\
>   Mavericks.app